# Expression can be simplifed and inline conditionals error

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have "expression can be simplified" and "Avoid inline conditionals" warning and I was wondering how I can fix it with this line of code?

```
myGameSwitch = myGameSwitch == true ? false : true;
```

Comment: `myGameSwitch = !myGameSwitch;`.

Comment: @sanketMakani Thanks a lot! That is much simpler than mine.